# Android Studio is not abstract and does not override abstract method on

Tags: java, android, service, callback

I'm trying to do a little app for get location with Google Play Service. The thing is, I'm having this error all the time and I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
//import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    gps = new MockLocationProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, Principal.this);
    net = new MockLocationProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, Principal.this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

  }
}
```

And the error is:

```
Error:(74, 8) error: Principal is not abstract and does not override abstract method onConnectionSuspended(int) in ConnectionCallbacks
```

If I don't implements `ConnectionCallbacks`, `OnConnectionFailedListener`, I have this error:

```
Error:(116, 41) error: incompatible types: Principal cannot be converted to ConnectionCallbacks
```

If I remove this options:

```
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
```

and don't implements `ConnectionCallbacks`, `OnConnectionFailedListener`, I don't have errors but `GooglePlay Service` is not connected.

I have this on Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate error you are getting is caused by your class `Principal` being declared as implementing the `ConnectionCallbacks` interface without implementing all the methods defined in that interface.  From the [Javadoc for ConnectionCallbacks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) we can see that this interface includes two methods:

> abstract void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
>   abstract void onConnectionSuspended(int cause)

You need to provide implementations for both of them, after which point your first error should go away.  There may be other problems in your code which appear after fixing this.